# Implement dynamically assigned roles for user groups

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a database with the following fields:

- ID
- First Name
- Last Name
- Email
- Phone
- Address
- Message
- ...

To keep things simple, let's say I have three user groups - user, super user and administrator.

I look for the best design (developing PHP-based application, based on CodeIgniter) that allow to the administrator to define field of view (user group A should have access to fields X, Y, Z) for diferent user groups, as well as the user himself must be able to choose which fields to see (from his group allowed for).

And this should be happen on backend, not frontend..

Any guidance?

Regards, Chris

Comment: This question is _not_ constructive. It's open for discussion that does not fit well SO. Have you read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Comment: for this purpose you should create another table named roles and in this(users) table add foreign key group_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you will find several approachs to that problem. It depends on the requirements and how functionality is expoxed and distributed in your modules.

In my case the access control was given on a controller basis, so I defined Abstract Controllers that can check the access in the constructor, p.e.:

```
class User_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() 
    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->auth->is_logged_in() || RedirectToLogin();
    }
}

class SuperUser_Controller extends User_Controller {

    public function __construct() 
    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->auth->is_superuser() || RedirectToBadUser();
    }
}

class Admin_Controller extends User_Controller {

    public function __construct() 
    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->auth->is_admin() || RedirectToBadUser();
    }
}
```

you should solve is_logged_in, is_superuser() and is_admin() based on yous specs,
then make your controllers bassed on one of those depending on the required level.

Anyway, nothing stops you to add a `$this->auth->is_superuser() || RedirectToBadUser();` inside a method, giving the granularity you need.